# dividing sub-categories by parent category - WordPress

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, hierarchical

I am aware this question is very similar to previous questions however none of the provided answers seem to work for me.

but my question is, how do I divide sub-categories by parent category?

For instance, If I click Balloons on this website (see first image), it then brings me to a new page where the sub categories are divided and the children of the sub category organised underneath it (see image 2 & 3).

This is the code I have, it gives me the desired functionality, however the layout is wrong, I want parent title followed by child images much like the layout in the images I have provided )(I am aware this is due to the hook I am using but I don't know the right one to use) EDIT: I have since changed the hook to 'woocommerce_after_subcategory' but that did not seem to work at all, they still display after subcategory title

```
// Adding Child Category List to Main Category Display Grid

add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID', 20);

function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($category) {
    $parent_category_ID = $category->term_id;
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0, // Set to 0 to show empty categories and 1 to hide them
        'parent' => $parent_category_ID,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcategories = get_categories($args);
    echo '<ul class="woo_subcategory_list">';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        $link = get_term_link( $subcategory->slug, $subcategory->taxonomy );
        echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$subcategory->name.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]